# UTF8 encoding error

Tags: python, unicode

I have some external data I need to import. How do I encode the input string as unicode/utf8?

Here is an example of a probematic line

> >>>'Compa\xf1\xeda Dominicana de Tel\xe9fonos, C. por A. - CODETEL'.encode("utf8")
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: The answer is given. But I suggest you invest some time learn about unicode, you won't regreat it :) http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.encode("utf8")` expects the source to be a unicode string. You are using it with a "regular" string which has "ascii" encoding by default. You should do something like:

`original_string.decode('original_encoding').encode('utf-8')`

In your case my guess would be:

```
'Compa\xf1\xeda Dominicana de Tel\xe9fonos, C. por A. - CODETEL'.decode("iso8859-1").encode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert bytes to a Unicode string use `decode` instead of `encode`.

Also that is not UTF-8. I guess it's [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1):

> >>> print 'Compa\xf1\xeda Dominicana de Tel\xe9fonos, C. por A. - CODETEL'.decode("latin1")
>       Compañía Dominicana de Teléfonos, C. por A. - CODETEL

Answer (score 1):

`encode` converts from a unicode string to a sequence of bytes.  `decode` converts from a sequence of bytes to a unicode string.  You want `decode`, because your data are already encoded.

More generally, if you're reading a string from an external source, you *always* want to decode, because there's no such thing as a "unicode string" out there in the world.  There are only representations of that unicode string in various encodings.  Unicode strings are like a Platonic ideal that can only be transmitted through the corporeal medium of encodings.